# How to track the resolution/aspect ratio of a WebRTC VideoStream in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, browser-api

My webapp displays a realtime video stream coming from a mobile device.
I need to take action when the video orientation changes.

Preferably I would want to subscribe for an event, but I did not find any such event on the `MediaStreamTrack` interface.

The closest thing I could find was `getSettings`, which according to MDN is supported since Chrome 53:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack

But my Chrome (v54) does not seem to know about this function.

I would appreciate any ideas, suggestions or even just background information on above mentioned feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

videoElement.onsize should be triggered. I doubt MediaStreamTrack.getSettings will trigger for a remote track...

Answer (score 0):

I bumped to the same problem trying to get the settings of a video track in chrome 55 and as you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/getSettings, getSettings is not supported yet in chrome. The web page you sited from mozilla is about the interface MediaStreamTrack in general, not about the specific method we want to use. So I think we are done with that approach.